# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c007b

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to start a App project and now i get the following error.

I tried a lot from the answers that i found here on the side, but I don't found my mistake.

Here is the output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: de.christian_heinisch.tiercheckliste, PID: 28372
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c007b (de.christian_heinisch.tiercheckliste:id/relativeLayout_for_About) for fragment AboutFragment{5abcffb #0 id=0x7f0c007b}
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28372 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
package de.christian_heinisch.tiercheckliste;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_pet_about) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_pet_info) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_pet_checklist) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_info) {

            AboutFragment aboutFragment = new AboutFragment();
            FragmentTransaction manager = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            manager.replace(R.id.relativeLayout_for_About, aboutFragment);
            manager.addToBackStack(null);
            manager.commit();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my fragment_about.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.christian_heinisch.tiercheckliste.AboutFragment"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_for_About">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my AboutFragment.java

```
package de.christian_heinisch.tiercheckliste;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {


    public AboutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `FragmentTransaction` replaces a `View` within your `Activity` hierarchy with your `Fragment`. The `View` with the ID `R.id.relativeLayout_for_About` is in the layout your are using for your `Fragment`, not the layout of the `Activity`. Add a `View` in your `R.layout.activity_main` where you want your `AboutFragment` to appear:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/placeholder_about"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then replace this `View` with your `AboutFragment`:

```
Fragment fragment = new AboutFragment();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.placeholder_about, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

You can read more about this paradigm in the [Developer Training docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).